# Is there any dataset that are monitoring the grounding electronic charges provided by the satellites?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication-satellite, scientific-data, historical-data

I would like to know if there are some datasets that are monitoring the grounding electronic charges provided by the satellites

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.